# Multiprocess write to one Pipe in python

Tags: python, linux, pipe

I am confused about the results when multi process write to the same pipe concurrently, here's the code:

```
#!/bin/python

import os
import sys
import time
from multiprocessing import Pipe

# generate pipe pair
parent_conn, child_conn = Pipe()
count = 0
# 1MB
size = 1024 * 1024

for i in range(0, 2):
    ret = os.fork()
    if ret > 0:
        # child process
        if i == 0:
            while True:
                recv = child_conn.recv_bytes()
                open("/tmp/pipe_test/%s" % count, "w").write(recv)

        if i == 1:
            while True:
                if count == 1:
                    break
                parent_conn.send_bytes("1" * size)
                count += 1
            sys.exit(0)

while True:
    if count == 1:
        break
    parent_conn.send_bytes("%" * size)
    count += 1
```

process will spawn 2 child processes, one to call `recv_bytes` to get data from the pipe, and another write data to the pipe, the main process also write to the pipe. So there is 2 processes write to one pipe, and one process receive data then write to local file.

I'd like to see that there are 2 files in `/tmp/pipe_test/`, one is full with "1" and another is with "%", and each of them is **1MB**.

But result is :

There are only one file which is `/tmp/pipe_test/0`, and it is **1MB**, there are both "1" and "%" in that file. Weird thing is, each "1" and "%" segment is right **16KB**, I have known that it may be associate with the **system page size** from the [pipe man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pipe.7.html) , but when I do the `getconf PAGESIZE` I got **4096** , not **16KB**

Another thing is, if I set the `size` variable to a smaller number like 1024, then the result is just what I want: 2 files in `/tmp/pipe_test/` and each of them is 1024, one holds "%" and another holds "1".

That would be great if somebody can explain this a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're a bit confused over how `fork` is used. You for example don't create sub processes the way you describe.

What fork does is to clone the process into a parent and child process, they are identical, with identical state except that in the child process `0` is returned and in the parent process the process id of the child is returned form `fork`.

This means that the loop in the first process will run `fork` (creating one child processes), but also that the first child process will when it returns from `fork` have the state that there remains one run of the loop left so it will run the loop the second time and create a grand child process.

Then you have a misleading comment `# child process`, the branch when `ret > 0` is only taken in the parent process (or from the first child, when it becomes parent of the grand child process). The branch where `tmp/pipe_test/%d` is created, is only taken when `i == 0` which only happens in the first round of the loop (and only in the first process), the file that's created then is `tmp/pipe_test/0`.

So the processes does the following:

1. A child process (2) is created, then it receives data from `child_conn` (being the same pipe for all processes) and writes to the `/tmp/pipe_test/0` (because `count==0` and you dont change it), it will do this in an infinite loop.
2. The child process will run the second round of the loop, create a child process (3), then the process will run the `if i==1` branch where send `1`s to the `parent_conn` and then exit.
3. The process will exit the loop and write `%`s to `parent_conn` and then terminate.

Now what happens when you write to the pipe concurrently you need to consult the `pipe(7)` man page. The buffer size for the pipe is not required to be the same as the page size, there's a separate define for the pipe buffer and it's `PIPE_BUF`. If you write blocks that are larger than `PIPE_BUF` the data is mentioned to be interleaved, but it doesn't mention that it will be in `PIPE_BUF` chunks.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will change the code to do more test.